# Error install nvidia-387: Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel:

Tags: drivers, nvidia, gcc

I'm trying to install nvidia-387 on my fresh Ubuntu 16.04.

Once I launch `sudo apt-get install nvidia-387` I always end up in the following outputs:

```
Building initial module for 4.13.0-26-generic
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 4.13.0-26-generic (x86_64)
```

During my searches I found lot of issues pointing to a wrong gcc version but after several attempts I wasn't able to find a way to go: following [this](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/940609/dkms-issues-with-nvidia-drivers-in-kernels-gt-4-3/%22this%22) discussion I tried with gcc 4.8/4-9/5.4/6 without any luck.

Any help?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Looks like the issue is cause by some shuffling of linux headers in some recent linux kernel updates.

Relevant discussion:
https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/1028016/linux/patch-for-compiling-v384-98-modules-with-linux-v4-14-9-/

I had the exact same issue and I fixed it by applying the patch suggested by user *PGNd*  in the discussion above.

Step by step instructions for manual edit of the nvidia src files on Ubuntu 16.04:

1. `sudo apt-get install nvidia-387` (this will fail)
2. `sudo nano /usr/src/nvidia-387-387.26/nvidia-uvm/uvm8_va_block.c`
   (you should replace `nvidia-387-387.26` with the version you are trying to install.)
3. Add the line `#include <linux/sched/task_stack.h>` before the other include statements at the beginning of the file
4. Run `sudo dpkg-reconfigure nvidia-387` to rebuild the nvidia driver
5. Reboot

This should work as a temporary workaround until nvidia releases a fix.
I was able to install cuda-9.1 after doing this.

Comment: It worked perfectly, you saved me! Thanks a lot!

Comment: This worked! For posterity this can also cause a login loop. You may have found yourself in this situation by trying to install nvidia drivers (in my case to get CUDA 9.1 running) prior to a fresh 16.04 install being fully updated. Initially the drivers may have appeared to work (on an older kernel) but then the update to 14.3.x left them in this broken state.

Comment: This didn't do anything for me on Mint 19.3 (Ubuntu 18.04 LTS). I am also wondering what the difference between nvidia-XXX and nvidia-drivers-XXX are in the package manager. The latter ones are more updated. Seems they changed the naming at some point.

Comment: I ended up rolling the kernel back to the default 5.0.0. This worked with the drivers.

Answer (score 0):

@adikus's answer did not work for me. Even after adding the header the build error continue to happen. What fixed the issue for me was upgrading the version of the drivers to [410](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers-410):

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-410
```

The compilation for this version succeeded and I'm now able to play games once again.